# What is jquery-1.4.1-min-vsdoc file for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to publish my ASP.NET MVC application. It is build successfully, but not publishing. Also, whatever the contents found in the publishing target folder is not running jQuery files properly. It is showing a warning:

> Warning 1 Error updating JScript IntelliSense: D:.. My application path.. \Scripts\ ****jquery-1.4.1.min-vsdoc.js***  : 'childNodes' is null or not an object @ 5814:4

I tried to replace this file from *[root/trunk/src/NBooks.Web/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min-vsdoc.js](http://www.assembla.com/code/nbooks/subversion/nodes/trunk/src/NBooks.Web/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min-vsdoc.js?rev=377#ln5814)*, but I am getting the same warning and not publishing application. Why is this happening?

I have also installed Visual Studio SP1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That one is just for getting intelliSense in Visual Studio. You don't need to publish it into the production environment.

If you take a look at the top of this file from below:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js

> This file has been commented to support Visual Studio Intellisense.
>    * You should not use this file at runtime inside the browser--it is only
>    * intended to be used only for design-time IntelliSense.  Please use the
>    * standard jQuery library for all production use.

Comment: ok, thanks . but why then VS not publishing application ? it populates the Error window with given warning!

Comment: ummmmm! it is there where it is showing the error and no changed with the name as it mentioned. still issue is there.

Comment: When you double click on it, it opens with no problem in VS?

Comment: Take a look at this one then:  http://devpinoy.org/blogs/comgen/archive/2009/06/24/visual-studio-2008-jquery-intellisense-fails-when-adding-jquery-ui.aspx